# What is the format of the standard claim script?

Tags: transactions, script, raw-transaction

With reference to this:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transactions#Pay-to-PubkeyHash

It would seem the claim script is simply the signature consisting of S and R and the public key.

However I know at least the signature gets DER encoded, which is fine I found a library for that, but I don't know the details. For instance is it:
DER(S,R)+pubkey, DER(R,S)+pubkey or DER(S+R+pubkey) and so on, there are many permutations etc.?

I'm looking for something like this where you can see what each byte is supposed to be:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short the answer is this:

```
InScript length                               : VarInt (1-9 bytes)
PushData operation of R/S/Hash_all/DER bytes  : OP_PUSH (1-9 bytes)
DER sequence type byte                        : 0x30
DER sequence length                           : 0x44-0x46
DER integer type                              : 0x02
DER integer length                            : 0x20-0x21
32 R bytes, left padded with 0x00 IF leftmost byte >= 0x80 - hence varying lengths above.
DER integer type                              : 0x02
DER integer length                            : 0x20-0x21
32 S bytes, left padded with 0x00 IF leftmost byte >= 0x80 - hence varying lengths above.
Sighash_All type byte                         : 0x01
PushData operation of publickey bytes         : OP_PUSH (1-9 bytes)
PubKey version/type byte                      : 0x04
Public key in 64 bytes of data - X and Y 32 bytes each
```

Answer taken from here:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=653313.0

After looking at it becomes pretty obvious that DER was a mistake on Satoshis part and something provided to him by OpenSSL.

I mean why encode unsigned integers as signed - then pad them to make them unsigned again.

Why these sequence and length definitions when we already know the length from the push byte op - why DER encode at all when its ALWAYS 32 bytes R followed by 32 bytes S?

Clearly its pretty silly.

Comment: More about OP_Push:
http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/29591/i-cannot-see-the-expected-op-code-in-transactions

More about VarInt:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Variable_length_integer

Comment: I think Satoshi used this DER-encoding just to pass the value to standard ECDSA_* methods from openSSL without any additional actions. And this allow changing (hard-fork) algorithm in future: we still have 255 prefixes (0x30 is in use for current).

Answer (score 0):

For Pay-to-Pubkey Hash, the standard claim script is two "push data" operations:

1. Signature: Approximately 71-bytes of DER-encoded sequence of R followed by S, then one additional byte for the [hashtype](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG#Hashtype_SIGHASH_ALL_.28default.29).
2. The public key that hashes to the value specified by the previous output and is also used during signature verification.

Comment: Ok so "DER encoded" is woefully inadequate. Its not a function people can call, but a certain pre-established encoding scheme.
I have to mark your question as a non-answer and post my own.

Comment: In my answer you can see for instance that it has been chosen to encode R and S as integers. Yes its DER encoded, but HOW? Someone who didn't know would have used the DER type for byte data!
I asked for details and I did not get it - hence this is a non answer.