# I cannot see the expected OP_CODE in transactions

Tags: script, transactions

According to different answers on this site the format of the standard TX claim script should be `[OP_PUSH DER(R+S)+HashType OP_PUSH PubKey]`

The `OP_PUSH` code is `4C`, `4D` or `4E` depending on push length.

However in this transaction I cannot see the expected code. I could not even find the definition of the one there:
https://blockchain.info/rawtx/db320e85d8bef3895052d9bf002aeb185fa12eeef8445e3e45f31b9a0c90f9f6?format=hex

`01 00 00 00` is txin index, `8C` is the scriptin length and then comes `49`.
Instead of `49` I would expect `4C`.

Is it because you can leave out the `OP_CODEs` or what am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[version]        01000000
[inputs]         01
[txid]           4f94da67fb56cf104850a03c3cbabdd4b0a38d7f47eadedaf670ee0d5fa296c8
[txout]          01000000
[in script len]  8c
[push signature] 493046022100e77bddaaae0f2e684776dff2e55f8d3654e78fbc9439fb53f4d73096eb1258c1022100aa4f0b33e1b99479a5a5a154773be244670d37ff6fd5da1bcc150e35c61fb51701
[push pubkey]    410485b6198b35faee9fb4f9ad6e809704057b930959fac62769858ed52b0cdf00015ad063612d2fe607e2b43f2f0bb4cf9169064872a971ae0be71e651412381d9e
[sequence]       ffffffff
[outputs]        02
[amount]         f44fc00200000000
[out script len] 19
[out script]     76a914fd69e5b61a949baf9c141e060b3c0c43f7637f5888ac
[amount]         9d7ded0600000000 
[out script len] 19
[out script]     76a914fe1a0e4a6163053f76cba0a7053850f07b34a7c288ac
[lock]           00000000
```

Comment: It isn't clear how this answers the question.

Comment: [push signature] 49... and [push pubkey] 41... are the codes. Note: all codes from 0x01 to 0x4b are also pushes

Comment: Hehe I really just needed this comment, but thanks :D